# Is it worth using PLINQ with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-dataset

Does anyone have experience using PLINQ with ASP.NET?  Is this a good combination, or something to avoid in most situations?

I develop an intranet ASP.NET site for a lawfirm (~100 users).  Several pages include non-trivial LINQ code, for example, we have a bank rec page that compares thousands of financial transactions between our accounting database and the bank's data, using LINQ to Datasets.  This is slow, so I am tempted to try PLINQ, but I am worried this could lead to 1 request monopolizing the web server.  Having the bank rec run 4 times faster but shutting all other users out while it is running would not be an improvement.

I know there are much faster solutions than LINQ, but I would rather have short code to maintain.

Right now, we have a Dual Pentium 4 web server, but I am hoping we can upgrade to decent hardware in the near future.

Comment: i have same question in my mind, please provide/mark answer..

Answer (score 1):

Just from what I've heard, there are only a few cases where PLINQ is slower than LINQ.  I hadn't heard any cases where PLINQ monopolized things as you described.  Microsoft has a session at PDC09 [PLINQ: LINQ, but Faster!](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT21).  I hope this video will help you decide if PLINQ is right for you, but as they say, measure before and after.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar concern.
I'm assuming plinq uses a backgroud thread from the thread pool, if this is the case then it would impact scalability  of the site. You get by default 100 threads per cpu if you have a low used site you might want to burn some extra threads per user request, but I'd do so very cautiously